# RichTextBox KeyPressArgs not working

Tags: c#

I have a `RichTextBox` that I want to track key presses and do something for each of the key press, e.g.`Ctrl + S` for save and so on. But my `RichTextBox` won't log key strokes. The `messageBox` does not pop  up at all.

```
  private void rtfContent_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'C')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is the code I am currently trying. The MessageBox is just there to actually see if the KeyPress was working and 'C' was just the first thing that came to mind.

Nonetheless my function does not do what it is supposed to. I have an `eventhandler` in my Designer

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.rtfContent_KeyPress);
```

Comment: It works for me, did you key in C (uppercase) or c (lowercase)

Comment: Clicking the checkmark beside an answer marks your question as solved in the UI. You do not need to (and should not) change your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've subscribed the form's `KeyPress` event (not the `RichTextBox`) to `rtfContent_KeyPress`.

Replace this:

```
this.KeyPress +=
    new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.rtfContent_KeyPress)
```

With this:

```
rtfContent.KeyPress +=
    new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.rtfContent_KeyPress)
```

Comment: Woops, was 45 seconds too late xD. +1 for same answer as me.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the KeyPreview = True i think, the keypresses is disable

[image]